# Web development, protecting application code

Tags: frameworks

I'm looking at some (PHP) Frameworks, and I just noticed this in the Laravel documentation:

> Like most web-development frameworks, Laravel is designed to protect your application code, bundles, and local storage by placing only files that are necessarily public in the web server's DocumentRoot. This prevents some types of server misconfiguration from making your code (including database passwords and other configuration data) accessible through the web server. It's best to be safe.

I'm familiar with CodeIgniter and CakePHP, as far as I know, these two frameworks don't do this. Should you really split it up and place your core logic outside of the webroot? In my experience, most clients use shared hosting and are not able to change their VirtualHost settings.

What kind of misconfiguration could you possibly do that would output your passwords? When developing, should you really do this?

Comment: overriding protection with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keeping only those files which should be publicly accessible in DocumentRoot is a best practice for [web application security](http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Security).  Consider:

- Every file which is private would need a rule configured with the web server to explicitly block it.
- Anyone adding files to the project needs to consider web server security settings. Simply keeping the files in separate directories makes it obvious what's public.  And developers don't need to change security configurations.
- Separating executable code and static files is a good practice anyway.
- Not blocking access to PHP scripts can cause unintended consequences. For example, you may have a script to update some DB records when run manually at the command line, so someone simply guessing a script name can run it over the internet.
- Monitoring for and cleaning malicious code written to the public directory is much easier if the real application logic is elsewhere.  See Wordpress breakins for an example.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP supports this - see [deployment](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html):

> CakePHP applications should have the document root set to the
>   application’s app/webroot. This makes the application and
>   configuration files inaccessible through a URL.